# PHP-FPM: don't process multiple requests in one moment

Tags: php, process, long-polling

I had VPS with CentOS 6.4 64bit. There is running Nginx 1.4.4 and PHP-FPM 5.5.6. I'm trying to make long-polling requests. However, if server is already processing one request, he doesn't respond to other. This mean, that if I have script with:

```
sleep(60);
```

PHP doesn't process other request. I must wait for 60 seconds. PHP status page is:

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           26/Nov/2013:22:02:00 +0100
start since:          148
accepted conn:        170
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     128
idle processes:       1
active processes:     49
total processes:      50
max active processes: 49
max children reached: 1
slow requests:        0
```

And je conf.d/www.conf:

```
[www]

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

user = apache
group = apache

pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.max_requests = 500

pm.status_path = /status

slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log

php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/wsdlcache
```

Comment: The **max children reached** is 1. That number should be higher if you want multiple requests to execute simultaneously. Check the nginx doc on how to increase it.

Comment: Do you use session in the script that handles those long polling requests?

Comment: Yeah, thanks so much! Yes, PHP sessions caused problem. Sessions was locked and other scripts must wait.

Comment: @weirdan thank you !!!!!!! Forgot session_write_close() ! Should be an answer.